# Entering data in d3.js

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am having a problem with loading data into d3.js. I have populated a `data.json` file with the following:

`"[[11,53,32.0,20],[4,57,160.0,20],[4,58,192.0,20],[2,63,352.0,20],[0,66,448.0,20],[0,67,480.0,20],[0,67,480.0,170],[0,67,480.0,320],[0,68,512.0,20],[0,69,544.0,20],[4,70,576.0,20],[0,70,576.0,170],[4,70,576.0,320],[0,72,640.0,20],[0,73,672.0,20],[0,75,736.0,20],[4,75,736.0,170],[0,76,768.0,20],[0,78,832.0,20],[0,79,864.0,20],[0,81,928.0,20]]"`

I want to load this data into JSON and then construct some objects using it. This is the responsible d3 bit:

```
frame.select("g").data(dataset).enter().append("img")
            .attr("src", "Shuttle Booster Diagram Simplified.svg")
            .attr("height", "150px")
            .style("background-color", "red");
```

However instead of loading the 20 rocket diagrams that I was expecting, this loaded some 300-plus of them!

If I knock the dataset down to

`"[[11,53,32.0,20]"`

It loads 15 copies.

What is my mistake? Should I populate the data some other way in order to avoid this issue?

The repo for this effort:
https://github.com/ResidentMario/visualizations/tree/master/shuttle

Comment: It looks like it's reading your data in as a string instead of as an array of arrays. Try removing the `"` from the start and end of your data.

Comment: remove the double quotes from data.json

Comment: Of course it's something that small! Thanks all, I've found and corrected the error